# How to print some statement to console while all others messages will be redirected to a log file?

Tags: python, shell, logging

I need to use a shell script to run python file and save all python script output to a log file. Below is a sample shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
python script.py > logFile.log 2>&1
```

However, I need to print some statements in python script out to a console.
For example, if the python script contains two print statements similar to below, the log file generated from the shell script will contain both statements, and I would like to also print statement2 to console.

```
print("statement1")
print("statement2") # also want to print this statement to console
```

I have tried using python logging module, but could not get it to work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should really use the logging module for this.

Try the following:

```
import logging

# Logging
log = logging.getLogger("log")
log2 = logging.getLogger("log2")
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log2.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
format = logging.Formatter(fmt = "%(asctime)s - %(module)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s", datefmt = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")

# For first file
logfile = logging.FileHandler("file.log")
logfile.setFormatter(format)
log.addHandler(logfile)

# For second file
logfile2 = logging.FileHandler("file2.log")
logfile2.setFormatter(format)
log2.addHandler(logfile2)

log.debug("test")
log2.debug("test2")
```

This creates two file handlers which can be used with `log` and `log2`.

Produces two files in the current folder: `file.log` and `file2.log`.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I wasn't being clear in my question. Instead of simple prints in my example, I have many operations using external modules such as tensorflow (deeplearning module), and I wanted to put the output of those operations (very lengthy) in the log (through redirecting). I would like to print to console the main results after all of the operations.. Not sure how I can use your example in my situation.